# Use crontab to start AnyDesk

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gtk, xdg-open

I am using AnyDesk on a Raspberry Pi 3. After around 6-7 days, it suddenly consumes all the memory and the device stops responding.

To prevent this, I am using `crontab` to execute `/usr/bin/killall anydesk` and stop anydesk.

I need to kill it on `0 * * * *` and start it again on `2 * * * *`.

However, it throws error saying `gtk warning cannot open display`.

I have tried using `export DISPLAY=:0` and it still doesnt work.
It keeps saying it cannot open Display 0. I have tried `0.0` and `1`.

There is `anydesk.desktop` in the `/etc/xdg/autostart/` which I tried to execute from `crontab` using `xdg-open`, but even that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because root doesn't have permissions to access the display.

I put it in my user's `crontab` instead of `sudo crontab` and it worked!

`export DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/anydesk --tray`